# Adding SVGs as an image type

Tags: file-uploads, image, file-manager

I'm trying to get a folder of SVG images (12,000 clip art images - don't ask) to show up in the File Manager.  If the folder it set to any file, they obviously appear, but when it's set to "image only" the SVGs don't show.

I've tried the obvious thing of adding 'svg' =>'image/svg' to config/mimes.php this means that they are able to be uploaded.  However this still doesn't mean that EE treats them as images.   Is there somewhere else I have to add svg to get EE to treat them as images?

Comment: Asked previously: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12729899/expression-engine-allowed-file-types-option

I assume you mean config/mimes.php...?

Comment: Yup I meant mimes.php rather than mimetypes.php - edited to reflect this cheers

Comment: Don't think you'll get a different answer from those I've linked to above though :(